# What are the best ways to show the statistics of Hours?

Tags: gui-design, data, user-centered-design, reports, analytics

I found one of the good option which Google is using "Popular Times" in Google Maps for the store searched. Below is a GIF showing a quick demo:

Any other idea or option can you suggest which has a good user experience too?

Thanks in advance guys for looking into it!

[image]

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem that broad to me. It's an interesting problem: to display best hours of the week visiting. To me, both examples in the demo and in the chosen answer are poorly catering to the users' need, be it a place owners or visitors. User has to flick 6 times to overview the whole week, this is insane! Also, averages on most popular and least popular hour spans are missing here. And the most/least popular days of week, too. Bar charts are not the only possible solution here.

Comment: Thanks Zoe!! I agree with you.. I dont know why this question was considered as too Broad, whereas I gave a very specific scenario. Yes I agree there can be many solutions to this issue.. but every question has many different solution and which is why we put on forums so we can get ideas from everywhere. Also thanks for highlighting the issues in the suggested designs. But can you please provide some suggestion which ca resolve the highlighted issues? Thanks once again!

Comment: I would, but I cannot add answers & images to a question on hold :-) In short, what I would do is a cell grid of 7 days on Y axis and 24 hours on X axis, and the density of visits should be shown by a density of color of each cell. So that the most visited hours are bright red, and free hours are green. Similar to traffic maps. This way you can fit the whole week in one screen or half of it. Plus some space for averages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not concerned about precision, you can list the hours of operation vertically and by each hour show icons of people in silhouette. The more people you show, the busier you are.

You could even arrange the icons side by side, which would basically turn them into (coarse-grained) bar charts.  That would give users an iconic display of the crowd plus a comparative indicator of what the most crowded times are.  Add a cash register and you get images of people waiting in line -- which is self explanatory -- where the length of the line is indicative of how crowded you are.

Here's an example:

---

[image]

---

Comment: @AT-UID my pleasure.  I updated the image to include a cashier so all those people appear to be waiting in line, as well as a few tweaks. Same general principle, but it communicates things even more effectively IMO,

Comment: This is fine, but really exactly what Google is already doing...just that the axis are tilted.

Comment: @DA01 Well the image is just one of the techniques I listed. It turned out to be the most pleasing visually, which is why I included it.  If time permits, I'll add more visuals and adjust the answer to make this clearer.  Thanks!