# Best way to allow entry of shop open hours

Tags: forms, gui-design, controls, web, time

I am looking for a control or a method such that I can allow the user to enter the working times of a shop for each weekday on a web page.

For instance, the working time for Wednesday is:

- 06:00 AM to 12:00 AM.
- 05:00 PM to 01:30 AM.

---

**@dan1111's Follow-Up:**

> Can there be an arbitrary number of opening times per day?

Yes.

> How often will this data need to be entered?

Only once upon shop registration.

> by whom?

System Admins.

Comment: More info on the requirements would be helpful.  Can there be an arbitrary number of opening times per day?  How often will this data need to be entered, and by whom (e.g. does a shop owner do this for own shop only, changing it rarely, or is the user someone managing business listings who has to manage the opening hours for hundreds of shops)?  Also, please show any interface you have so far for the page where this will go.

Answer (score 4):

If you like graphical solutions you may try something like this:

[image]

Clicking in the stripe below the edit field helps to select the hours without typing them. User may also click and drag, if they like.

Comment: I think your solution/suggestion is a little bit overwhelming. There are too many numbers to see at once.

Comment: @Behdad I agree. Though, it's just a wireframe, a concept. It requires some artwork to become a design.

Comment: IMO this design would be better off with a single 24-hours timelline.

Answer (score 4):

How about something where admins can click/drag the hours for each day. You could provide extra feedback of the actual hours selected during this action.

[image: open hours]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to collect working times:

[image]

Comment: why do you need the extra checkbox? - if you delete all time slots for that day then the shop is closed

Answer (score 0):

I think this needs work on making it more obvious on what you should do, but I think this is probably about as efficient as you'll get in terms of clicks. It also should be quicker for the shop keeper to make updates.

It's based on how I envisage a shop keeper might write down his time table:

```
M,T,W,F: 8:30 - 18
T: 8 - 12, 13 - 20
S: 10 - 16
S: Closed
```

So you start with the most common occurrence and then add in more specific cases. You start with all the days in the top box (closed), and a default schedule.

[image]

You then set the schedule and click for each of greyed out days that it applies to. And add extra more specific schedules further down.

[image]

To the side, you could have an version of what it will look like on your site. See the earlier [UX.SE question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/89466/which-is-a-more-intuitive-open-hours-and-days-schedule-board) on ways to display the times.